# HTML5 (XHTML style strict format of coding)

Tags: html, xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

Like the title says, what exactly does that mean? Ive tried googling for answers but I still dont understand? so the entire document has to be in a HTML5  format right? and the syntax has to be in strict XHTML?

so is this the correct header to use in this situation? Thank you so much :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
       <title>Page Title</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure XHTML is dead now.  Just use HTML5 syntax.

Comment: HTML5 is *not* XHTML and there is *no* XHMTL5 proposal. It is HTML5 or XHTML(1.1). In any case, see [Is XHTML5 dead or is it just an synonym of HTML5?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149839/is-xhtml5-dead-or-is-it-just-an-synonym-of-html5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [polyglot HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-polyglot/html-polyglot.html). It's still HTML, but "could be served" as XML.

This is how the base structure looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is another article: http://www.xmlplease.com/xhtml/xhtml5polyglot/

Comment: Be warned that if you serve this up as XML, you'll lose the use of entity references such as `&nbsp;` and `&eacute;`. XML only knows about five named entities. HTML on the other hand, recognises all of them. (A solution would be to compromise and use a full XHTML DOCTYPE declaration; the XHTML DTD contains a list of entities.)

Answer (score 1):

The normal doctype (see [HTML syntax - doctype](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#doctype-syntax)) for HTML5 is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

You can also use *deprecated doctypes*, but the term says pretty much everything about them.

And, no, HTML5 markup does not *need* to be valid XHTML, in the empirical sense that HTML5 markup might be both valid HTML and non-valid XHTML/XML.

Three meaningful considerations are:

1. in HTML5 `<br>` is allowed and `<br/>` is too.
2. a  closing `/>` on non-void elements does not behave like it does in XML: it's ignored, you cannot have auto-closing entities.
3. HTML5 introduces a set of so-called semantic tags (`nav`, `footer`, `article`...), that are not specified in XHTML.

Regarding point 2, this is not valid:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Dummy</title></head>
    <body>
        <div/>
    </body>
</html>
```

you have to write:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Dummy</title></head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

See [HTML syntax - elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements) for more information.

Comment: Also, <script> elements in XML are always PCDATA and dynamic (data)-attributes are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

check the required syntax of each element in HTML5 according to web specs

http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/index.php 
provides a syntax section for each element:
e.g.

http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/doctype/html5_doctype_syntax.php